# Printing a Word document in colour using VBA code to print

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I have a Word document that we do not want the users to edit once it had been generated from the database. We have set up a VBA module to print the document automatically after opening, but we need this to print in colour. At the moment, it will only print in colour if that is what the computers default printer settings are, and the majority of users forget to change their settings. Is there any way to specify that the document prints in colour in the VBA module?

Comment: Can you share the portion of code you use to print please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the PageSetup.BlackAndWhite property.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834921.aspx